# Johansen's cointegration test in small sample under non-normality

Tags: time-series, references, normality-assumption, small-sample, cointegration

I am looking for **references** regarding the behaviour of Johansen's cointegration test (trace test, perhaps also eigenvalue test) in small samples with non-normal innovations.

1. I wonder how robust the test is to deviations from normality (which is mostly relevant in small samples but not so much asymptotically, if I understand it correctly).
2. Also, I wonder whether Engle-Granger test could be preferred to the Johansen's test in small samples under any circumstances.

Something "light" like a **textbook** treatment would be preferred to technical articles. (I am not ready to dig very deep, but I need a citation for my research paper.)

The most relevant references I was able to find are the following:

1. Silvapulle & Podivinsky ["The effect of non-normal disturbances and conditional heteroskedasticity on multiple cointegration tests" (2000)](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00949650008811997#.VSaJJ_mUe50)
2. Johansen ["A Small Sample Correction for the Test of Cointegrating Rank in the Vector Autoregressive Model" (2002)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/3082025.pdf)
3. Hubrich et al. ["A Review of Systems Cointegration Tests" (2001)](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1081/ETC-100104936#.VSaJb_mUe50)
4. Cheung & Lai ["Finite‐sample sizes of Johansen's likelihood ratio tests for cointegration" (1993)](http://web.calstatela.edu/faculty/klai/KLPaper/OBES93Au.pdf)
5. Gonzalo & Lee ["On the robustness of cointegration tests when series are fractionally integrated" (2000)](http://www.eco.uc3m.es/~jgonzalo/fijas.pdf)

Silvapulle & Podivinsky (2000) is quite relevant and quite readable, and basically answers my first question. Still, I wonder if there are more studies to confirm or contradict their findings. 
Johansen (2002) is about small samples but not really about non-normality. Also, it is more about fixing the small sample problem rather examining the negative effects of the problem. Moreover, it is pretty technical and hard to digest. 
Hubrich et al. (2001) examine a wide range of conditions but do not seem to provide overarching conclusions (perhaps they do not exist, though). 
Cheung & Lai (1993) do not seem to discuss non-normality. 
Gonzalo & Lee (2000) suggest that when the series are fractionally integrated rather than I(1), Engle-Granger test is preferred both in small samples and asymptotically to Johansen's test. So they answer my question number 2. I am still interested in other examples.

Comment: I think the general conclusion is that its performance is quite terrible in small samples. A recent strand of papers have improved its performance using bootstrap methods, perhaps you'll find useful citations in these papers' introductions. For example, have a look at recent publications by Anders Rahbek.

Comment: @hejseb, thanks for the idea! I will check these out.

Comment: Not a textbook treatment, I know, but perhaps this might be of interest as well http://www.taloustieteellinenyhdistys.fi/images/stories/fep/f1995_2d.pdf

Comment: A more complete reference for the link above: Tor Jacobson "Simulating small sample properties of the maximum likelihood cointegration method: estimation and testing" (1995).